# How to perform k-mean clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining, credit-card

I am trying to explore a [creditcard fraud dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) to learn R and also k-means clustering. But I encountered an issue while getting the optimal number of clusters. Unfortunately, not many findings about that error or even how to performing kmeans clustering in R can be google. I would like to know what's the warning about? And why the result only show 1 cluster? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
data = read.csv("creditcard.csv")
scaled_data <- scale(data )
wss <- (nrow(scaled_data)-1)*sum(apply(scaled_data,2,var))
for (i in 2:100) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(scaled_data, centers=i)$withiness)
plot(1:100, wss, type='b', xlab="Clusters", ylab="WSS")
```

Warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= 14240350) 
2: did not converge in 10 iterations 
3: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= 14240350) 
4: did not converge in 10 iterations
```

Comment: This is not an error, but a _warning_. And as it says, convergence was not reached after 10 iterations. Either allow for more iterations, or lower your threshold for convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with your code. Let's go through it using an example data set available on R since you did not provide reproducible data:

```
data(iris)
scaled_iris <- scale(iris[, -5])
```

Since the data have been scaled, all of the variances are 1 so this is all you need to compute the total:

```
wss <- sum(colSums(scaled_iris^2))
wss
# [1] 596
```

Now the the clustering. I'll include the argument that @mhovd mentions with its default value (there is no argument for convergence). If you get the warning increase `iter.max=` to 15 or 20 or more. This does not guarantee that your results for any number of groups are optimal. To increase the chances of that you should use the `nstart=` argument and set a value of 5 or more:

```
for (i in 2:100) wss[i] <- kmeans(scaled_iris, centers=i, iter.max=10)$tot.withinss
head(wss);tail(wss)
# [1] 596.00000 220.87929 138.88836 113.97017 104.98669  81.03783
# [1] 3.188483 2.688470 2.716485 2.535701 2.497792 2.116150
plot(wss, type='b', xlab="Clusters", ylab="WSS")
```

Note you misspelled `withinss` and you did not realize that `kmeans` returns their sum as `tot.withinss`. It is always good to read the manual page `?kmeans`. Note that you do not need 1:100 since the plot function will automatically supply consecutive integers if you provide only one vector.

[image: Plot]

Comment: I have updated the code a bit above. I have another question is about evaluating the prediction with kmeans.  By using "confusionMatrix", i see another Error - "data and reference should be factors with the same levels". Anything I missed?

Comment: This is not an updating of your code. This is a completely different question involving at least two packages that you do not identify (?clue and caret?). You. should open a new question for this. Since you do not provide the original data (or a sample of it), it will be more helpful if you use the `iris` data set to illustrate your problem.